# Is there any way to predict if the ISS will lose its signal or to know it directly?

Tags: iss, nasa, development, api

I am currently working on a project by using the ISS livestream:
https://video.ibm.com/channel/iss-hdev-payload

But sometimes there is a loss-of-signal and it displays a screen that breaks the experience. Is there a way to detect this moment? Have you any idea?

I know why it happens, but it's hard to detect with my knowledge.

Maybe an API that gives us something in live?

Comment: What screen does it display ? "... and it displays a screen that  ..." What is "*it*" ? What does your project do ?

Comment: The Livestream displays/broadcasts a message that says : "The video the space station [...] has been interrupted due to [...] loss of signal between the station and the communications network [...]". I just want to show the livestream on a website and when the iss lose the connection, we have a fallback of another video.

Answer (score 6):

The most common cause of loss of video feed from the ISS is due to a TDRS handover.

See this map below.

[image: A map of the ISS orbit, as seen in Mission Control]

Note the large regions enclosed in light blue, green, and yellow.  Those define the boundaries of where the three TDRS satellites can reach.  As ISS traverses its orbit, it has to switch which TDRS satellite it talks to, and the handover takes a certain amount of time, as they have to quite literally swing their high gain antennas back over to point at the new satellite and lock on to it.  For normal handovers, this takes maybe 30 seconds, but then look at the text over India where it says ZOE.

ZOE means "Zone of Exclusion", and it's the area bounded on the left by the yellow and on the right by the green boundaries.  That is the region of orbit where ISS can see neither TDRS-W (labeled T171W) nor TDRS-E (labeled T046W).  You'll also notice that there is a satellite just south of ISS labeled T275W -- that's TDRS-Z, which is not typically used unless ISS is doing critical operations like a spacewalk or preparing for arrival or departure of a visiting vehicle.

This non-use of TDRS-Z is for a few reasons:

- ISS is not the only customer of the TDRS network, nor is it even the #1 priority customer (ISS is #2).
- TDRS-E and TDRS-W are both reachable from the primary TDRS ground site near White Sands, NM.  TDRS-Z requires a separate ground station in Guam.  That adds additional latency and expense.

When ISS is in the ZOE, it has no satellite connection to anybody.  Depending on the latitude this happens at, the resulting loss of signal can last between 5 and 10 minutes.  This loss of signal also provides flight controllers a convenient opportunity to get up, stretch their legs, go to the bathroom, refill their coffee, etc.

Comment: Is there any way for a random internet user to get LOS predictions? I think that's really what the question is about.

Comment: Best way would be to pull up an ISS tracker that shows the current position.  LOS in general is pretty well predicted by the longitude.  Alternatively, you could look at the telemetry streams (e.g., here https://iss-mimic.github.io/Mimic/ ) and keep an eye on the antenna angles (S-band and Ku-band elevation angles are the most relevant)

Comment: That's so interesting, thanks to your answer I understand way better. But still have some question : I saw that there are more than 2-3 TDRS, what are the others for? And sometimes the LOS appears in regions that which seem to be in one of the areas of a tdrs, why ?

Comment: @renadr Some of the TDRS birds are "hot spares" -- basically waiting and ready to take over if one of the main ones conks out.  My understanding also is that the others functionally live in the same general area (within a few degrees longitude) and serve to increase available bandwidth to customers rather than increasing coverage.  In the areas where there is a TDRS, you'll see handovers happen, which result in a loss of low data rate comms for ~15 seconds and a loss of high rate data (including video) for a minute or so.  This is due to the time it takes to swing the antennas around.

Comment: @renadr You also have to account for line of sight from the ISS antennas to TDRS satellites being blocked by other components of the ISS (like solar arrays). No one but NASA is going to be able to predict those, since you have to know ISS attitude along with BGA and SARJ angles.